# How to pass parameter to sql 'in' statement?

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

I want to create this query:

```sql
select * from products where number in ('123', '234', '456');
```

but I can't find any example of achiving this with Npgsql and NpgsqlParameter. I tried like this:

```cs
string[] numbers = new string[] { "123", "234" };

NpgsqlCommands cmd = new NpgsqlCommands("select * from products where number in (:numbers)");
NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("numbers", numbers);
command.Parameters.Add(p);
```

but it didn't work ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Pass it as an array:

```
string[] numbers = new string[] { "123", "234" };

NpgsqlCommands cmd = new NpgsqlCommands("select * from products where number = ANY(:numbers)");
NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("numbers", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text);
p.value = numbers;
command.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Comment: this will generate an error: your `array` variable should be `numbers` in the parameter value

Comment: @UwConcept: honestly, it is a long time since I last used `NPgSQL` and don't even have a `VS` installed to check :)

Comment: @Adrian: is the syntax OK or you had to correct it? I cannot check.

Comment: Use NpgsqlDbType | NpgsqlDbType.Numeric if you pass an int[]. Also I think its $numbers not :numbers? Other than that the syntax worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically create your command string -  loop with your first parameter as :num0, second as :num1 etc. When you've added all of them, remove the last character "," and replace it with ")".

Comment: if you can use an array in the way Quassnoi suggest, I'd got with that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Quassnoi answer I'll add this one to show, how we done it in real code.

Warning! This working code is from real project and can damage your beautiful approaches!

```cs
string commstr = "SELECT product_name, price, product_url, image_url FROM products WHERE id  = ANY(@arr);";
NpgsqlCommand cm = new NpgsqlCommand(commstr, cn);
NpgsqlParameter arpar = new NpgsqlParameter();
arpar.ParameterName = "arr";
arpar.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Bigint;
arpar.Value = PerformQuerySphinx(query, limit);
cm.Parameters.Add(arpar);
```

Answer (score 1):

use "delete from test where id IN (select unnest(@ids))"

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer for ~2021:**

You can use `ANY` like this:

```
WHERE id = ANY (@ids)
```

Then when you add your params, do this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ids", ids.ToArray());
```